# How to pass simple user input from Vue to Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create something simple with Laravel + Vue.js without having to use the database.

I have two inputs from a Vue Component, and I was wondering how I pass those two values back into a Controller.

Usually, you use Axios to complete CRUD functions, but I honestly just want to pass simple values to the backend, and then have the backend transfer an array into back to the Vue Component.

Any advice? All the decent tutorials online usually use a database to transfer data back and forth.

Comment: use axios to call the route

Comment: use axios or fetch if you want to send with ajax request and do not want any reload. Or use `form` tag with post method and correct action url. Then add button with type `submit` inside form element before closing it. After submit the page will refresh and you can pass any data from controller to view back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send data back and forth using axios

Here is what I had for my Vue Component:

```
<template> ... </template>
<script>
    export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            days: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
            axios.get('/api/urihere', {
                params: {
                    name: this.name,
                    days: this.days
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        }
      
    },
    mounted() {
        // 
    }
}

</script>
```

While I had you had a simple get for Routes

```
Route::get('/urihere', [UrihereController::class, 'someMethod']);
```

and inside the said-controller

```
public function someMethod(Request $request)
{
    return [$request->name, $request->days];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [inertiajs](https://inertiajs.com/)?

inertiajs allows you to create fully client-side rendered, single-page apps, without much of the complexity that comes with modern SPAs. It does this by leveraging existing server-side frameworks.